# Deep copy of array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, deep-copy

I made a class:

```
class configurations
{
    public double lowColumn1 = -1;
    public double highColumn1 = -1;
    public double lowColumn2 = -1;
    public double highColumn2 = -1;
    public double lowColumn3 = -1;
    public double highColumn3 = -1;
}
```

I want to make an array (`con1`), and make a copy of it (`con2`).
I would like to change `con2` so it  **will not change `con1`**.

I think it is called deep copy, is it?

It is important that the copy will not consume a lot of running time, efficiency is important.

I tried `.Clone()` function which didn't help me.

Please tell me what is the most efficient way to adjust my code.

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    configurations[] con1 = new configurations[3];
    con1[0] = new configurations();
    con1[1] = new configurations();
    con1[2] = new configurations();
    configurations [] con2 = new configurations [3];
    con2 = (configurations[]) con1.Clone();
    con2[0].highColumn1 = 999;
}
```

please do not make this as a duplicate. my program is very heavy and in other topics they do not discuss time efficiency. in addition to this aspect. i am very new to programming, and i couldn't made adjustments from other answers of other questions.

Comment: In which way didn´t `Clone`help you? Please be more specific on what you´ve tried.

Comment: .clone() didn't help me because the value of con1[0].highColumn1  changed to 999, and i wanted it to stay -1.